# MVC - How to display bootstrap tooltip for the cells with data ONLY

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have the following `html`:

```
<tr class=@(item.Index % 2 == 0? "even" : "odd")>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ProductId)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ProductName)</td>
    <td id="cost" title="@item.Data.ToolTip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ProductCost,"Currency")</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ToolTip)</td>
</tr>
```

and a `jquery` for toggling tooltip:

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#cost').text() != '') {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    }
});
```

I want to display `tooltips` only in case if cell has a data.
The way I have does not seem to be working.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a span into the td and have the tooltip on the span. Then if there is no content in the span - hide it. Also note that you need to have unique id's for the table so that #cost might needs to be altered if you have more than one row with this struture.

```
<tr class=@(item.Index % 2 == 0? "even" : "odd")>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ProductId)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ProductName)</td>
    <td id="cost"><span title="@item.Data.ToolTip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body" data-placement="right">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ProductCost,"Currency")</span></td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data.ToolTip)</td>
</tr>
```

and a jquery for toggling span:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $('#cost span').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() === '') {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked! Can you explain me please, why `span` fixed it? Also, I have solved it in different way. I just modified `XML` file by removing the data for the `ToolTip` element and it also worked

Comment: hey - glad it worked - it works because hte element that has the tooltip in the original example was the td - irrespecitve of the content of that - by using a span and filling that span with the data - then having the tooltip pon that span separates it from the td and so if its empty - the td does not have the tooltip to display.. Glad to have helped - cheers :)